# Skype does not disappear from task manager after ending session

Tags: windows-xp, skype

Why sometimes when I click exit Skype it closes but it's in task manager eating my RAM?

Process don't *eat*. I mean it wont use CPU cycles and wont take more/less RAM. Process takes about 150 mb. Nothing happens when I click `End Task`. It's just sits there and won't release that initialized space, I can't start virtual machines because the there arent any free RAM space  I can't sign in in Skype because of `Can't open Skype. You are already signed in on this computer. Please signed out try again` error. Logout doesn't work too. Only restarts helps. Any ideas?

**Edit**
I forgot to mention that the OS wont continue loading while skype won't Sign In.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Skype icon in the notification area by the clock and select Quit and that will terminate the process.  You may be prompted if you really want to quit.   Be sure to click Quit here as well.

The item on the task bar will not really exit Skype.  You should see a grey Skype icon with an X near the clock in the Notification area, not on the task bar  [Notification Area Info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279771)

Comment: You don't understand :) The problem is when I click Quit the Skype closes but wont terminate the process.

Comment: Just so I am clear.  You do this from the icon in the notification area?  Not from the open app when you are finished using it.

Comment: Yes, from task bar.

Comment: Please see my edited reply

Comment: Ouh GOD! Your not getting what I mean. I click EXIT Skype not Sign Out. If you didn't know, exit shutdowns Skype. My problem is that sometimes Skype closes (no X ICON INT TASKBAR) but PROCESS EXISTS (HALTED)!!! I didn't want to be rude.

Comment: Exactly. Killing the process doesn't help. Going to Resource Manager from TaskManager and trying to end the process (tree) gives "Access Denied"